# Simple FB.ui Dialog

Tags: facebook

I have a fb.ui modal popup on my page to let users update their status on my page. It works great so far. Now i tested and it seems to be that the postpicture, title and description are automatically pulled from my page - I didn't define them in my script. It doesn't look very nice to be honest, and i would like to remove that for my users benetit, because it looks like they are directly advertising my page. Is there any way to have the fb.ui dialog in a simple way, only that their message will be published?

Thanks for all your kind help!

EDIT: MY CODE

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the fb.ui feed page for a list of parameters being passed:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Some options like name, description and image will be generated automatically based on your page content, you can set them to an empty string or something more appropriate from within your code.

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!',
     description: '',
     name: '',
     picture: _some_default_picture_
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```